# Invalid cast error occurs in calculating elements in the listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trying to calculate the median value from Listbox data in C#.
However, occurs invalid cast exception occurs in foreach statement as below (in bold) :

foreach (**string item** in ListBox1.Items)

can anyone help me how to fix this error? will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

```
private void calcButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    medianList.Clear();
    ListBox2.Items.Clear();

    if (sourceList.Count == 0)
    {
        double tInt;
        foreach (string item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(item, out tInt) == true)
                sourceList.Add(tInt);
        }
    }

    if (ListBox1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        if (RadioButton1.Checked)
            MiddleMedian();
        else
            AllMedian();
    }
    else
        return;

    DisplayResults();
    sourceList.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean ListBox1.Items.Text?

Comment: I tried a similar approach, ListBox1.Items.ToString. but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: dear i said ListBox1.Items.Text. Plus what are you using Xamarin , WPF ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, isn't the error message meaningful?

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

```
foreach (string item in ListBox1.Items)
```

So you have added integers to the `ListBox1`. Then this fixes it:

```
foreach (int tInt in ListBox1.Items)
    sourceList.Add(tInt);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful. However, what should I do if I wish to support double data type rather than integer? could you please show me another code for that?

Comment: @HappyBono: i don't see how you add the integers to the ListBox. But you can always add doubles. Also, if `sourceList` is a `List<double>` the `int` is implicitly converted to `double` at `sourceList.Add(tInt)`. So i don't understand where you are struggling with.